# What is the mapping class group of the wedge of circles?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering if there is a description of the mapping class group of a wedge of $n$ circles.

Are the only kinds of homeomorphism classes in the mapping glass group are compositions of permutations of the circles and maps which send a circle to its inverse?

What about maps which send a circle from the wedge to a multiple of another circle? By multiple, I mean concatenating a circle several times.

Or maps that send a circle to two other circles concatenated?

Comment: My guess is that it's the outer automorphism group of $F_n$. This is a pretty complicated group.

Comment: The group of self-homotopy equivalences is indeed $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$. The group of self-homeomorphisms up to homotopy is just a finite group permuting and reflecting the circles. "Mapping class group" means different things to different people.

Comment: Ah, of course, most of the automorphisms of $F_n$ can't even act as bijections. Silly me.

Comment: Thanks! This answered most of my questions.

Comment: To follow up the answer of @GrumpyParsnip, the group you get is the signed permutation group on $n$ symbols. http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Signed_symmetric_group